# How to open file in new Pycharm window from the command line

Tags: pycharm

**How do I open a file in a new (detached) window** using the command line?

I am currently able to open files in the pycharm editor (on ubuntu) using

```
xdg-open /path/to/file
```

These files are not opened in new windows in pycharm. Instead they are opened in the docked editor.

Selecting a file in a project window and hitting `shift enter` lets you open a file in a new window. So this functionality is built into pycharm.

[image]

## How would I invoke this command using a terminal command?

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-files-from-command-line.html), but in short, you need to pass line number along with path to script.

Example:

```
pycharm --line 3 ~/MyProject/scripts/numbers.js

pycharm ~/MyProject/scripts/numbers.js:3
```

Comment: This only opens the files. I want to open them in a new (detached) window.